# Linking a facebook app's page to an existing facebook business page

Tags: language-agnostic, web-applications, facebook

I have a facebook app page, and a separate facebook business profile page.

The business page was created, but not by me, some time before the app and its page were created.   **Is there any way to connect the two pages, or import the content and friends from one to the other?**

The older profile page has some content; a set of friends and wall posts that I don't want to lose.  It was created before I had a chance to set up an app page.  Since the app was created more recently, it does not have any content posted to it.

I intended the app page to eventually hold some advertising info for my main website itself (non-canvas, just using fb for the connect api etc).  The idea being that as people sign up on my site through facebook's OAuth, I could use the graph api to post to their wall.

The wall posts are working as expected but naturally they are directing users to the facebook app page, which has no content, friends etc. I'd prefer to be directed to the original business page, where the party is really happening.

Now it seems that the two pages are completely separate; what would I need to do to direct the users to the business page?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Are you trying to do this from code? You mention the graph API, but the question seems to be more about Facebook account features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot link those two pages, they have different purposes: describing a topic (company/band whatever) and a describing an application.

What you can do to drive users to the business page is inserting an attachement to your wall posts, users will focus on them and thus be less likely tempted to click on the application that sent the post.
Attachement with images are more powerful too.

have a look a the documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments

use the href attribute for the link to your business page.

hope this helps

Comment: "You cannot link those two pages, they have different purposes: describing a topic (company/band whatever) and a describing an application."

This makes sense if you are, for instance, a car company that has a car maintenance FB App, so you have a fan page for the car brand, and and an app page for the FB App.  However, if your company is just a website, then the FB App may BE your company/brand. 

For example, Rotten tomatoes has two pages:

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=326803741017
http://www.facebook.com/rottentomatoes

Surely it doesn't make sense to have both?